# Knockout writable computed observables

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm currently building a very number-heavy application using Knockout and I've ran into a problem with making a computed observable writable.

Currently I have a dropdown option where the user selects an age group and the selected value from this populates the text input next to it to show the population for that age group which is a computed observable. Both the dropdown and the text input values are populated from an array.

I have set up a codepen below but basically you'll see that the text input's value is generated via a computed observable and the correct formatting (via a custom binding handler!) is applied when you select a value from the dropdown.

The problem I'm having is that if you enter a custom value into the text input (inputted straight into the textbox as opposed to selecting a value from the dropdown) then when you blur out of the textbox, the custom formatting isn't applied to the value that you input and I'm pretty unsure how to go about tackling this problem.

```
self.selectedPopulation = ko.computed({

    read: function () {
      return self.chosenAge().population;
    },

    write: function (value) {
      // write value back here?
    },

  });
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HkguL
(write function is at Line 76.)

Comment: This doesn't directly answer the question you're asking; but I think custom binding handler is the wrong way to tackle the formatting problem.  I'd generally store the unformatted data in an observable and have a read-only computed that adds formatting for display only.  If they need to edit a number, it shouldn't have commas in the edit box, in my opinion.  Even if you do let them edit with a read-write, I still can't see the need for a custom binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've need to make the selectedPopulation a normal observable, and subscribe to the chosenAge observable to be notified when it changed.

You'll need to create chosenAge with a dummy object to stop knockout blowing up on binding:

```
self.chosenAge = ko.observable({age: '', population: ''});
```

And then change your computed to an observable:

```
// Selected population
self.selectedPopulation = ko.observable('');
```

And subscribe to the chosenAge observable:

```
self.chosenAge.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    self.selectedPopulation(newValue.population);
});
```

I've not used CodePen before, but I've updated your code [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pLHvw) in case I've missed anything in my working example.

Comment: This is almost there. We're a lot closer, so thank you. The only problem is that if you select a value from the dropdown, then enter a custom value, the custom value gets writted to the associated dropdown item so if you then go back and flick between the options available in the dropdown, you'll see your custom value is associated with whatever option was selected at the time. The values need to be reset each time and go back to the original values should you enter a custom value and then go back to a dropdown list... codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uepEy

Comment: Ah, I was wondering about whether that's what you wanted or not! Updated to a simpler solution that should do what you want now.